# How to add $elemMatch of mongodb in java code?

Tags: java, mongodb

this is my query
db.collectionname.find( {"nodes._id":"core","nodes.attvalues":{"$elemMatch":{attr:"last_mod_date",value:{$gte:"2023-09-17T00:00:00Z",$lt:"2023-09-24T00:00:00Z"}}}}).count();

I want to use it in my java code.

The below code is giving me the data.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'00:00:00'Z'");

        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime then = now.minusDays(8);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("nodes._id","core");
query.put("nodes.attvalues.attr","last_mod_date");
query.put("nodes.attvalues.value",new BasicDBObject("$gt",then.format(format)));
query.put("nodes.attvalues.value",new BasicDBObject("$lt",now.format(format)));
```

But I want to that how can i update the current code with the above mongo query and fetch the required data from the db.

The collection looks like this.

```
[
  {
    _id: '55f6d14b5ddb3ae7d5d08a7b',
    _class: 'com.somfy.pcpwebapp.domain.SWOGraph',
    label: '5100188/C - Make - Gray ',
    mode: 'directed',
    type: 'workflow',
    nodes: [
      {
        _id: 'core',
        label: 'core',
        type: 'core',
        attvalues: [
          { attr: 'creation_date', value: '2015-09-14T13:53:06.000Z' },
          { attr: 'designation', value: 'LEAFLET UTIL. DEXXO PRO RTS' },
          { attr: 'distribution_sites', value: [] },
          { attr: 'distribution_workflow_ids', value: {} },
          { attr: 'flow', value: '1' },
          { attr: 'flow_to_task_definition_ids', value: [ [Array] ] },
          { attr: 'last_mod_date', value: '2023-09-20T07:23:30.093Z' },
          {
            attr: 'last_mod_user_id',
            value: '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2'
          },
          { attr: 'last_mod_user_login', value: 'marith01' },
          { attr: 'manuf_exists_offserie', value: '' }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: 'MethodsSite',
        label: 'MethodsSite',
        type: 'task',
        attvalues: [
          {
            attr: 'assignable_user_ids',
            value: [
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669cf',
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2',
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669da',
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669d9',
              '55f29e07618fe271f2c57227'
            ]
          },
          {
            attr: 'assigned_user_displaynames',
            value: [ 'MARINO Thierry', 'RAZNIK Pascal' ]
          },
          {
            attr: 'assigned_user_emails',
            value: [ 'Thierry.MARINO@simu.com', 'Pascal.RAZNIK@simu.com' ]
          },
          {
            attr: 'assigned_user_ids',
            value: [ '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2', '55b66bb127772e0efc3669d9' ]
          },
          { attr: 'comment', value: '' },
          { attr: 'completed_date', value: '2015-09-15T06:30:05Z' },
          { attr: 'completed_user_id', value: 'MARINO Thierry' },
          {
            attr: 'completing_date',
            value: '2015-09-15T06:29:29.843Z'
          },
          {
            attr: 'completing_user_displayname',
            value: 'MARINO Thierry'
          },
          {
            attr: 'completing_user_email',
            value: 'Thierry.MARINO@simu.com'
          },
          {
            attr: 'completing_user_id',
            value: '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2'
          },
          { attr: 'last_mod_date', value: '2015-09-03T06:30:05Z' },
          { attr: 'last_mod_user_login', value: 'MARINO Thierry' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    _id: '55f6d14b5ddb3ae7d5d09a8b',
    _class: 'com.somfy.pcpwebapp.domain.SWOGraph',
    label: '5100188/C - Make - Demo ',
    mode: 'directed',
    type: 'workflow',
    nodes: [
      {
        _id: 'core',
        label: 'core',
        type: 'coree',
        attvalues: [
          { attr: 'creation_date', value: '2015-09-14T13:53:06.000Z' },
          { attr: 'designation', value: 'LEAFLET UTIL. DEXXO PRO RTS' },
          { attr: 'distribution_sites', value: [] },
          { attr: 'distribution_workflow_ids', value: {} },
          { attr: 'flow', value: '1' },
          { attr: 'flow_to_task_definition_ids', value: [ [Array] ] },
          { attr: 'last_mod_date', value: '2015-09-30T07:23:30.093Z' },
          {
            attr: 'last_mod_user_id',
            value: '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2'
          },
          { attr: 'last_mod_user_login', value: 'marith01' },
          { attr: 'manuf_exists_offserie', value: '' }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: 'MethodsSite',
        label: 'MethodsSite',
        type: 'task',
        attvalues: [
          {
            attr: 'assignable_user_ids',
            value: [
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669cf',
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2',
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669da',
              '55b66bb127772e0efc3669d9',
              '55f29e07618fe271f2c57227'
            ]
          },
          {
            attr: 'assigned_user_displaynames',
            value: [ 'MARINO Thierry', 'RAZNIK Pascal' ]
          },
          {
            attr: 'assigned_user_emails',
            value: [ 'Thierry.MARINO@simu.com', 'Pascal.RAZNIK@simu.com' ]
          },
          {
            attr: 'assigned_user_ids',
            value: [ '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2', '55b66bb127772e0efc3669d9' ]
          },
          { attr: 'comment', value: '' },
          { attr: 'completed_date', value: '2015-09-15T06:30:05Z' },
          { attr: 'completed_user_id', value: 'MARINO Thierry' },
          {
            attr: 'completing_date',
            value: '2015-09-15T06:29:29.843Z'
          },
          {
            attr: 'completing_user_displayname',
            value: 'MARINO Thierry'
          },
          {
            attr: 'completing_user_email',
            value: 'Thierry.MARINO@simu.com'
          },
          {
            attr: 'completing_user_id',
            value: '55b66bb127772e0efc3669e2'
          },
          { attr: 'last_mod_date', value: '2015-09-15T06:30:05Z' },
          { attr: 'last_mod_user_login', value: 'MARINO Thierry' }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

query.put("nodes._id","core");
query.put("nodes.attvalues",new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",new BasicDBObject("attr","last_mod_date")));
query.put("nodes.attvalues.",new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",new BasicDBObject("value",new BasicDBObject("$gt",then.format(format)))));
query.put("nodes.attvalues.",new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",new BasicDBObject("value",new BasicDBObject("$lt",now.format(format)))));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code worked and got the required result:-

```
query.put("nodes._id","core");
query.put("nodes.attvalues",new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",new 
BasicDBObject("attr","last_mod_date")));
query.put("nodes.attvalues.",new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch",new 
BasicDBObject("value",new 
BasicDBObject("$gt",then.format(format)).append("$lt",now.format(format)))));
```